# Question on Torah-study principles

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study

It is explained (Selections from Likkutei Sichos, Shmos, Parashat Tetzaveh, p. 483) that one of the principles of Torah study is to minimize the number of differences between the positions of the Sages. This can be found, according to the author, in the work "Sdei Chemed, vol. 10" and "Darchei Shalom, K'lallei HaShas, sec. 257".

I've been searching on HebrewBooks.org, but unfortunately could not find any of these works and in particular, these chapters describing these principles. Does anyone know where I can find these?

Also, the Rogatchover Gaon (Tzafnat Pa'neach) in his work the Michtevei Torah writes “Everything that is written in the Torah represents a law, not – Heaven forbid – a story.”. Does anybody know where I can find this letter online? Also on HebrewBooks.org, I was not able to find it.

Thank you very much in advance. Your help is much appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: Thank you very much all, That is why I really like this forum :). To help each other. Kind Regards,

Comment: happy to oblige :-) if you feel any of the responses suitably answer the question please select the check mark. We look forward to you sticking around and learning with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source in Sdei Chemed can be found on the Otzar HaChochmah website [here](https://tablet.otzar.org/book/book.php?book=200387&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16091555989699682&pagenum=68) (penultimate paragraph on left side). It writes there:

> אלא נלע"ד שעיקר הטעם שראו חז"ל לקבע כללי הלכות הוא מפני שרבו מחלוקת החכמים ברוב דיני התורה וחשו למחלוקת בישראל ושלא תעשה תורה כשתי תורות ח"ו ע"כ קבעו כללי הלכות בהסכם כל חכמי ישראל או רובם
>
> But according my own opinion, the main reason that Chazal saw to fix halachic rulings is because there are many arguments of the chachomim in the majority of Torah laws, and they are worried that it will create arguments amongst Israel and the Torah shouldn't become like two Torahs G-d forbid. Therefore, they fixed the halachic rulings with the agreement of all chachmei yisrael or the majority of them.

The source in Michtevei Torah can be found in letter 99 [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1018&st=&pgnum=45&hilite=) on Hebrewbooks (last two lines of right column). He writes there:

> כי כל מה דכתיב בתורה הוא דין לא ח"ו סיפר

Comment: The quotation from Sdei Chemed is referring to rules for deciding BETWEEN those who are arguing, not  how to decide what they are arguing about or how to interpret the argument.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not an answer, but this is a very widely accepted and fundamental rule referred to by authorities as אפושי מחלוקת/פלוגתא לא מפשינן. See [here](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%9F&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) for a collection of examples on
Sefaria, and [here](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%AA%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%9F&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) for an extremely thorough listing of sources for this rule and possible limitations.